# Node.js - Mosca & Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mqtt, mosca

I built a server on node.js that use Mosca and MQTT.

On my localhost everything worked find, including get/send messages via mosquitto (_sub/_pub).

When I uploaded the code to Heroku, the mqtt request worked inside the server, but I saw nothing on mosquitto.

That is my code to run the MQTT broker.

```
import { ServerOptions, Server, Client } from "mosca";
const settings: ServerOptions = {
    port: 1883,
};
const ms = new Server(settings);
```

To publish messages via node.js I used those lines of code:

```
import * as mqtt from "mqtt";
const mqttServer = mqtt.connect("mqtt://localhost:1883");
mqttServer.publish(`testTopic`, `testMsg`);
```

I used the http url of the heroku ( `http://<app>.herokuapp.com` ). 
I tried to get the `testMsg` via mosquitto_sub like that:

```
> mosquitto_sub -h <app>.herokuapp.com -t testTopic
```

And no luck.

If I use the localhost version and type `mosquitto_sub -t testTopic` it's work.

Why not in Heroku?

(By the way, I should mention, I use typescript.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku will only expose a web app via HTTP (on port 80 or 443 for HTTPS). It will not forward incoming data on port 1883 to the application instance.

If you leave mosquitto_sub long enough I expect it will print an error about failing to connect.

If you want to host a MQTT broker on Heroku you will need to use MQTT over Websockets most likely with HTTPS on port 443